# How to implement multiple selection in primefaces datalist?

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

I am trying to keep track of selected items from a `<p:datalist>` by use of a `<p:selectBooleanButton>`. I am using the below snippet for rendering the list.

```
<p:dataList value="#{movies.lazyModel}" var="movie" id="movies" paginator="true" rows="10"
   paginatorTemplate="{FirstPageLink} {PreviousPageLink} {PageLinks} {NextPageLink} {LastPageLink}"
   type="none" paginatorAlwaysVisible="false" lazy="true" rowIndexVar="currentRow" >

   <p:panel id="movieInfo">

     <!-- content markup -->

      <div id="rent">
         <p:selectBooleanButton offLabel="Add to Cart" onLabel="Remove from Cart" id="btnRent"
            value="#{movies.checkedItems[currentRow]}">
            <p:ajax update="btnRent" listener="#{movies.updateCart()}" event="click" process="btnRent"/>
         </p:selectBooleanButton>
      </div>

   </p:panel>

</p:dataList>
```

**BackingBean**

```
@ManagedBean(name = "movies")
@ViewScoped
public class MovieListBean extends BaseBean implements Serializable
{
   private static final long serialVersionUID = -1887386711644123475L;

   ....

   private boolean[] checkedItems;

   @PostConstruct
   public void initialize() 
   {
      int totalRows = serviceLocator.getMovieService().getCatalogSize();
      checkedItems = new boolean[totalRows];
   }

   ....

   public void updateCart()
   {
      if (lazyModel != null)
      {
         int selectedIndex = lazyModel.getRowIndex();
         System.out.println("Selected row in datalist - " + selectedIndex);
         System.out.println("Object instance associated with selected row - " + lazyModel.getRowData());
         System.out.println("checkedItems[" + selectedIndex + "] - " + checkedItems[selectedIndex]);
      }
   }

   public boolean[] getCheckedItems() {
      return checkedItems;
   }

   public void setCheckedItems(boolean[] checkedItems) {
      this.checkedItems = checkedItems;
   }

}
```

I have seen solutions on SO as well as the documentation which demonstrates the same by using `<f:setPropertyActionListener>` but it requires you to use an `ActionSource`, namely a commandButton or commandLink. Also, most of them are for `<p:dataTable>`.

This is not the case in my example as I have to add/remove objects from the collection as well as update the count in the header text. This would be achieved in the listener but it does not seem to get triggered.

So, my question is how do I change my approach while still using dataList. Using above snippets also breaks the pagination.

I am using JSF 2.1 (Mojarra) + PrimeFaces 3.5

Answer (score 0):

To enable action components in a `<p:dataList/>` you need to wrap the group of components in a  `<p:column/>`

```
     <p:dataList value="#{movies.lazyModel}" var="movie" id="movies" paginator="true" rows="10"  paginatorTemplate="{FirstPageLink} {PreviousPageLink} {PageLinks} {NextPageLink} {LastPageLink}" type="none" paginatorAlwaysVisible="false" lazy="true" rowIndexVar="currentRow" >
         <p:column>
              <p:panel id="movieInfo">
                 <div id="rent">
                    <p:selectBooleanButton offLabel="Add to Cart" onLabel="Remove from Cart" id="btnRent" value="#{movies.checkedItems[currentRow]}">
                  <p:ajax update="btnRent" listener="#{movies.updateCart()}" event="click" process="btnRent"/>
                    </p:selectBooleanButton>
                 </div>
             </p:panel>
         </p:column>
     </p:dataList>
```

Comment: I tried the same. But as you can see, I cannot use a commandButton or commandLink since I have to add/remove items on the fly and display the same UI wise. Therefore, I thought of using a selectBooleanButton which is similar to selectBooleanCheckbox. Is there anyway I can implement using these components ? Or if possible maintain UI-state if using action components is the only way (with pagination under consideration) ?